# php: cookie based sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, memcached

does any body have any info/links as to how to integrate a cookie based session system? i've used file/mysql, and am currently using memcached. i wanted to play with apc sessions, but thought i'd give a go at cookies, only i don't know much about it.

i imagine i'd have to write my own session handler class?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You mean storing session data in cookies? Is that a good idea?

Comment: Please note that cookies can only store a maximum of `4KB` of data.  This is generally why you do not see cookie based session storage.  Also take into consideration that a number of users have cookies turned off entirely or set to restrictive access with their browsers security policy.

Comment: @cballou: Regular old sessions usually use cookies too. They just store the SESSID though, and the rest of the data is stored on the server. Although I think PHP will try stuffing the SESSID into the `GET` param if cookies are disabled.

Comment: @Pekka yes, it's a good idea if you have a very high volume site
@cballou ya i know about that restriction.. note that 'a number of users' having cookies off is fairly invalid. less than 1% of visitors do, and most of the time, those are bots

Answer (score 5):

In PHP session data is usually stored in a file. The only thing stored in the cookie is a session identifier. When sessions are enabled and a valid session cookie is found, PHP loads the users session data from the file into a super global called funnily enough SESSION.

Basic sessions are started using `session_start();` called before any text is sent to the browser. then items are added to or removed from the session object using simple array indexing eg.

```
$_SESSION['favcolour'] = 'blue';
```

later...

```
$favcolour = $_SESSION['favcolour'];
```

basic cookie only sessions (no local storage) can be created with a call to

```
 set_cookie('favcolour','blue'[,other params]);
```

before any text is sent to the browser, then retrieved from the cookie superglobal

```
$favcolour = $_COOKIE['favcolour'];
```

you don't need to call `session_start()` if doing cookie only sessions.

the optional [,other params] are more advanced and can be read about here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Sessions can become a very complex discussion, I'd suggest doing some light work in them and then expand your knowledge.

DC

all you ever wanted to know about PHP sessions

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

DC

To reuse PHP's session handling code you will need to add a write handler using `session_set_save_handler` and then do exactly nothing in that handler. That's because its called after the output to the browser is closed therefore you cannot send anything to the browser.

Before writing non header data to the browser use the set_cookie functions and store the contents of the $_SESSION array (after serialising and encrypting) into a cookie. when the applications start you can read the cookie unserialise it and put it into the $_SESSION array.

That's a quick hint at what to do as I have never done it, I prefer to write all my own cookie code. There may be some gotcha's but its not hard a few tests should find any gotcha's.

DC

Comment: I probably wouldn't go cookie-only though, especially if you don't want users to tamper with (or read) the data.

Comment: if you have a very busy website file based sessions are too resource intensive. but if I wanted security above all else I'd use a db, because files can be read.

Comment: i dont need to know how to use sessions. i fully understand that. cookie based sessions (not identifier storage in cookies) is a valid technique that minimizes the number of server db/file/cache lookups, and stores all the data for a session in an encrypted cookie. i guess no one here understands what i mean.

Comment: The second part of the above answer ("basic cookie only sessions") shows you how to use cookies for a "browser session" ie it lasts till the user closes the browser. the encryption is up to you. This method uses no db/file/cache lookup

Comment: BTW if you have more than 4k worth of data (varies with browser) then it will fail.

Comment: thanks for the follow up DC. the 4k isn't, i hope, a limit i would reach. most sessions should be very small, way less than 1k, so i wouldn't come up against that.

in the second part of your answer above, you've only shown how to store a value in a cookie, not how to specify a session handler using session_set_save_handler and define all the methods for the session to be automated to a cookie based session. i think it's tough to find info on because it's a very unique approach. thanks for your thoughts tho!!

Comment: Why didn't you ask that in the first place? See additional comments in the answer.